# Web page load time tracking sites

Tags: web-services

I want to track and analyze web page load times on my user's systems.

I ran across this article http://www.panalysis.com/tracking-webpage-load-times.php that uses Google analytics to track pages, but it's too coarse for my needs.

Are there any sites out there that specifically let you track page load times using a JavaScript snippet you embed in your web pages?

Ideally the snippet would look like this:

```
var startTime = new Date();

// code to load the tracker

window.onload=function() {
  loadTimeTracker.sendData(<customer id>, document.path, new Date() - startTime)
}
```

Comment: presumably you're looking for a logging/tracking type app, not a dev-time thing like yslow and firebug's net tab?

Comment: Correct!

I edited the question to try to clear that up.

Answer (score 1):

[Gomez](http://www.gomez.com/) has a service that tracks how long your website takes to load. It doesn't use any JavaScript as far as I know.

Another good resource is http://webpagetest.org/. It allows you to test the load time manually, but offers a lot of analysis of your page. Latency, time to first byte, assets, DNS lookups, etc. Great resource.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking to send data back to server?  If not there are lots of tools to track this sort of thing.  i know the firebug extention for firefox does.

if you are looking to send the data base to server doing it purely with javascript will have some drawbacks because it wont include page rendering times, only the time from the when the first line of javascript was recieved until the page finished loading which may skew your data.

Answer (score 1):

[Jiffy](http://code.google.com/p/jiffy-web/) is pretty nice and open source.

Answer (score 0):

Enable trace on your page, that might be the good start to analyze how much time your page takes to load.

Comment: That only tells me how long it takes the page to load on my system.  I want to know how long it takes to load on the user's system.